# Summing vertical distance from scatterplot points to plotted line in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I currently have a plot in Matlab in which several thousand points are plotted in the form of a scatter plot from data imported from a *.csv file. Using the `hold on` command I have also plotted a linegraph on this same plot which consists of 6 points. All of the scatterplot points I mentioned, lie above this line.

A simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
hold on
plot(results.data(:,9), results.data(:,10),'LineWidth',1.5) % linegraph
plot(results.data(:,5),results.data(:,6),'.','Color', [0.9290 0.6940 0.1250]) % first group of points
plot(results.data(:,3),results.data(:,4),'.','Color', 'r') % second group of points
hold off
```

I'm now trying to sum the distances of all of these thousands of points (regardless of group) to this line, and preferably write this value to a variable in the workspace. Is there a way to do this in Matlab? I'm a bit unsure where to start at the moment, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Well, if you have 2 points, you should be able to fit a line of the form `y=mx+n` with no problem. Then simply, for each x of your points, compute the y of the line. The difference between the y of the point and the y of the line is the vertical distance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! So to implement this, I would first determine an equation for every line segment, then use an `if` loop to determine if a pt is in the x-range of a given line segment, then compute the y-value of the line equation corresponding to the point, and lastly take the difference of the y values to get the vertical distance.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.